# Where is Captain Obvious? SQL view not returning correct results

Tags: sql, view

The answer might be staring at me in the face but I obviously need someone to point it out to me.

OK, I'll try and be as clear and concise as possible.

I'm using C# and SQL Server 2012 and attempting to select from a SQL view and return the results sets as a list. I get results but they are not exactly what they should be. I use the same SQL Server view using two different ways of selecting from the view with same parameters being passed. One using lambda and the other using `SqlQuery<>`.

Result set is not correct:

```
agentEmailLicRegions = _db.vGetRegionAlerts
                          .Where(x => x.region == region && x.titlealerts == true)
                          .OrderBy(o => o.Email)
                          .ToList();
```

The above call executes and I capture this in SQL Server profiler:

[image]

I can take the capture query and run it in SSMS and it returns the correct result set. However running the SQL call in code the returned results are not correct. Some results are missing and some are duplicated.

Below is a snapshot of the two different result sets.

**Bad** results:

[image]

**Good** results:

[image]

Returns correct result set:

```
agentEmailLicRegions = _db.Database.SqlQuery<vGetRegionAlert>("select * from vGetRegionAlerts where region = '" + region + "'" + " and titlealerts=1 ORDER BY EMAIL").ToList();
```

I'll be glad to provide more information if needed. The key points for me is that the captured SQL query that is fired from the lambda expression can execute successfully in SSMS. This has me baffled.

Comment: Could it be, that `_db.vGetRegionAlerts` reads the data more than once? Check the row count...

Comment: Check to make sure the two queries are hitting the same server. I have seen this sort of thing happen when one was hitting Qa and one was hitting Prod.